# sub-menu, making a div appear

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page like this
on the left side a submenu like this :

```
<div id="submenu1">Menu 1</div>
<div class="submenu2">Menu 2</div>
```

on the right I have the content window associated to each of those menu like this

```
<div id="menuwindo1">Window associated with menu 1</div>
<div id="menuwindo2">Window associated with menu 2</div>
```

Ma goal is to make that when we click on the Menu 1 div (on the left) it makes the related window appear and when we click on an other menu div it makes tis window appear while making the other disappear.

I honnestly don't know how to do it... some suggestions?

I tried to find it on other post but either the other questions were too specific or the answer given didn't work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of its low quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've demonstrated an idea of how you may implement the side submenu navigation bar and main content window and switch the contents on click using jQuery. Hope, it helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submenu2").click(function() {
    $("#window1").hide();
    $("#window2").show();
  });
  $("#submenu1").click(function() {
    $("#window2").hide();
    $("#window1").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-navbar {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: red;
  float: left;
}

#submenu1,
#submenu2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.window {
  height: 100vh;
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

#window1 {
  background: yellow;
}

#window2 {
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-navbar">
  <div id="submenu1">Menu 1</div>
  <div id="submenu2">Menu 2</div>
</div>
<div class="window">
  <div id="window1">Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content of submenu1Content
    of submenu1Content of submenu1</div>
  <div id="window2">Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2Content of submenu2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried this code... doesn't work

Comment: Run the snippet code I have used, it is working. Did you import jquery.js into your html code? Without it, you cannot make use of Jquery functions.

Comment: no just a mistake frome me.. seems to work... will try to apply it thx

Comment: Rate it up and mark it,if it helped. Cheers.